# Reset audio.duration to "00:00" when function stop() is triggered

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

This is straight from MDN web docs: video and audio APIs.

"there is no stop() method on the HTMLMediaElement API — the equivalent is to pause() the audio, and set its currentTime property to 0. Setting currentTime to a value (in seconds) immediately jumps the media to that position."

So how would I set the audio.duration property ('duration-time' span) to "00:00" when Stop() is triggered?
This is the code. all the failed attempts are commented out.

```
<span id="songName">Muzika Audio-Player</span>
                <div id = "timebox">
        <span id="current-time">00:00</span> <strong>/</strong> <span id="duration-time">00:00</span> 
    </div>

let curtimetext = document.getElementById("current-time");
let durtimetext = document.getElementById("duration-time");

function stop() {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        playbtn.innerHTML = "<i class = 'fa fa-play'></i>"; 
        document.getElementById("glow").classList.add("disable-animation");
        document.getElementById("songName").textContent = "Muzika Audio-Player";
        //durtimetext.innerText = "00:00";
        //document.getElementById("duration-time").innerText = "00:00";
        //durtimetext.innerHTML = "00:00";
        //document.getElementById("duration-time").innerHTML = "00:00";
        //durtimetext.textContent = "00:00";
        //document.getElementById("duration-time").textContent = "00:00";
    }
```

Comment: I copied this and the commented out lines work fine on their own. I only tested .innerText and .innerHTML but I assume they all work. Make sure there are no errors happening before that which is causing the function to stop prematurely

Comment: ok thanks, I checked and it all seems fine no errors...
I havn't included the whole code but perhaps its not working on my end because there are audio files involved?

Comment: **innerHTML** should work. In your `stop` function try testing with just these 3 lines... `audio.pause(); audio.currentTime = 0;` followed by `document.getElementById("duration-time").innerHTML = "00:00";`